# google python class strings2.py exercise E

Tags: python, string

What happens at this line ? Why -1 ?

```
if n != -1
```

E. not_bad
Given a string, find the first appearance of the
substring 'not' and 'bad'. If the 'bad' follows
the 'not', replace the whole 'not'...'bad' substring
with 'good'.
Return the resulting string.
So 'This dinner is not that bad!' yields:
This dinner is good!

```
def not_bad(s):
    n = s.find('not')
    b = s.find('bad')
    if n != -1 and b != -1 and b > n:
        s = s[:n] + 'good' + s[b+3:]
    return s
```

Comment: In the future, looking up the documentation for the methods you're using is a *whole lot* faster than asking a question on SO.  You can google `"python string find"` or do `help(str.find)` in your interpreter to have an answer in under 10 seconds.

Comment: okay sorry for that question. i was just confusing about this and did not thought that it is described in the python docu. thx a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-1 means the substring could not be found.

From the [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

> Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such
>   that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure.
>   Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is
>   the same as for slices.

Answer (score 0):

str.find(sub[, start[, end]])
Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found, such that sub is contained in the slice s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. **Return -1 if sub is not found.**